# If else statement error

Tags: php, if-statement

What problem with my if else statement that I coding with HTML code.

```
if($target_networks == 1){
'<ul class="list_a"><li>' . $target_networks. '</li></ul>'
}else{
'$target_networks'
}

Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc.php on line 59
```

Comment: Welcome to PHP, you need to add `;` and don't forget to echo your strings.

Comment: 1 small remark not relted to your problem though, it's strange to see you use a list if there's 1 item, and not when there's more than 1. Just saying :-)

Comment: also putting $target_networks into '' will not work. and no echo to show message ;)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put **;** after every line. It is not JavaScript but PHP.

```
echo $target_networks ? '<ul class="list_a"><li>' . $target_networks. '</li></ul>' : $target_networks;
```

this will work, also variables should not be put into '' literal because they will not be parsed.

Comment: And to echo the data.

Comment: Yes. I've edited with proper example :)

Comment: Ah wonderful shorthand if statement

Comment: There is no sense in using {} if they are not needed, also ==1 is not needed. Why to write so many code if it can be shortened.

Comment: What happens if `$target_networks` equals 2? or any other non-zero integer. With your code it would still resolve to true which may not be what is desired

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
if($target_networks == 1){
 echo '<ul class="list_a"><li>' . $target_networks. '</li></ul>';
}else{
 echo $target_networks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if ($target_networks == 1) {
echo "<ul class=\"list_a\"><li>$target_networks</li></ul>";
} else {
echo $target_networks;
}
```